# How do I set class string variables with keyboard input?

Tags: java, class, methods, setter

I am working on a project where I have a class named dBase with getter and setter methods for fields such as first and last names. However, When I run the code, line 6 of the code portion is highlighted with a java.lang.NullPointerException error, which doesn't help me at all.

How do I make this work?
Thanks, in advance

```
case 3:
input.nextLine();
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++){
System.out.println("Enter first name of student " + (i + 1));
String firstN = input.nextLine();
roster[i].setfName(firstN);
System.out.println("Enter last name of student " + (i + 1));
String lastN = input.nextLine();
roster[i].setlName(lastN);
    }
        break;
```

Comment: The above snippet is not helpful, can you add more code

Answer (score 2):

You didn't include the full source which means I just have to guess, but, usually, this is the problem:

When you write something like:

```
class MyThing {}

MyThing[] x = new MyThing[10];
```

what you're doing is creating an array that is capable of holding references to 10 myThings. *It does not create 10 myThings*. It doesn't create any MyThings at all, in fact. You still have to actually make them. For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) x[i] = new MyThing();
```

*NOW* you've created 10 mythings (that loop runs 10 times, each time, it makes a mything, that math works out).

Answer (score 0):

I would say that your array String[] roster is not initialized correctly.
If you do not know how many elements your array will contain, I would recommend using an ArrayList instead of a standard String array.